# iOS 7 UIStatusBarStyle Hide Status Bar During Application Launch Bug

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, statusbar

I am updating my app to change the colour of my Navigation Bars from White to Blue. Therefore, I want to change the colour of the Status Bar from black to white.  I've tried EVERYTHING from the Apple documentation, which helped me change the Status Bar Style for all my View Controllers in my Storyboard.

However, any nib I push to that is not in my Storyboard using presentViewController automatically changes the UIStatusBarStyle - here's my code for the push:

```
NSString *url = @"https://twitter.com/Example";
                NSString *title = @"Example";
SocialWebViewController *addController = [[[SocialWebViewController alloc] initWithURL:url title:title] initWithNibName:@"SocialWebView_iPhone" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:addController];
[self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I've already placed the UIStatusBar preferred style in my AppDelegate, which WORKS, BUT ONLY for the ViewControllers in my StoryBoard:

```
- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
```

AND YES, I've already tried:

(1) `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleDefault];`

(2) `[self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];`

(3) Set the UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance to YES in the plist

NONE of this works for those Nibs not in my StoryBoard.

OK SO I FIGURED OUT WHAT YOU GUYS HAVE BEEN SAYING - SETTING View controller-based status bar appearance TO 'NO' HAS NOT BEEN WORKING FOR ME BECAUSE MY STATUS BAR IS INITIALLY HIDDEN DURING APPLICATION LAUNCH, WHICH HIDES IT ALL THE TIME WHEN I SET UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance to "NO"...How do I fix this?

Comment: Shouldn't UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance be NO? That way, it does not change automatically.

Comment: Its not bug, its feature.

Answer (score 7):

In your `*-Info.plist` file set the keys:

```
UIStatusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyleLightContent
UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance = NO
UIStatusBarHidden = YES
```

And in your `AppDelegate` add this line to method `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
```

Comment: Yes, this is the solution the op is looking for

Comment: By setting the "Status bar style" to that in the info.plist does not do anything.  Also, setting the "View controller-based status bar appearance" to "NO"/"False" just hides the status bar.

Comment: @user2981416 did you cleaned the project?. I'm testing this right now in a simple project and works fine.

Comment: Yes I did clean the project. That's strange. Are you testing this with a storyboard of NavigationControllers or nibs?  Because it works fine for me with all my ViewControllers in my Storyboard, but not for nibs I push to using presentViewController.  Maybe can you try it for MailComposer? See what happens when it opens up a draft message.  (I can supply you with code to use MailComposer if you don't know how to do it)

Comment: I'm testing with a Storyboard. The fact that the behavior changes with the nibs could be a result of using "UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance to YES". Since you said that when you set that key to NO you hide the status bar, made me think that maybe you are setting the key "UIStatusBarHidden" (Status bar is initially hidden) to YES

Comment: boggled as to why Hiding the status bar during application launch messes everything up. Thanks for you help by the way.

Comment: I think that the name "Status bar is initially hidden" is quite confusing. What this key does is to hide the status bar at launch time and will remain hidden until you set the property "statusBarHidden" from the sharedApplication to NO explicitly. That is why when you set this to YES, the status bar disappears. So, to make it visible again AFTER the app launch, in your app delegate you have to set the property to NO.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the style of the bar to be light in the entire application the easiest way is to set UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance to NO and then do

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];`

Otherwise simply setting the preferredStatusBarStyle in the UIViewController should work without any other modifications.

```
- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
```

My suspicion is that you are using a UINavigationController/UITabBarController etc to show the UIViewController. If that is the case then you will need to subclass UINavigationController/UITabBarController in order to add the correct status bar style you will need to subclass these controllers to add the preferredStatusBarStyle method to them. Simple implementation of such thing would be as follows

**UINavigationControllerSubclass.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UINavigationControllerSubclass : UINavigationController

@end
```

**UINavigationControllerSubclass.m**

```
#import "UINavigationControllerSubclass.h"

@interface UINavigationControllerSubclass ()

@end

@implementation UINavigationControllerSubclass

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}

@end
```

Just use that instead of UINavigationController and the status bar should now be light.

You always have to think about stack of controllers when dealing with this kind of UI issue. Since the UINavigationController contains the UIViewController if you set the status bar property in just the UIViewController, the UINavigationController does not know about it and keeps its original property. That is why creating a subclass of UINavigationController and setting the status bar style there fixes everything. If you ever run into this kind of issue just try to remember that.

Comment: Hi, I edited my question because I just noticed something with why it doesn't work for me when I set UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance to NO.  When I change Hide Status Bar During Application Launch to YES (which is what I want to have happen) causes the status bar to be hidden the whole time.  But when I change it to NO then like you all have been saying, the status bar colour appears to be white...how do I fix this?

Comment: set the statusBarStyle to be dark instead of light if you want it to be black text

Comment: I actually want it to be white, but don't want to have to set Hide Status Bar During Application Launch to YES for this all to work...?

Comment: you don't need to hide it on launch for it to work. just implement the  preferredStatusBarStyle in the UIViewControllers you want to be white or use [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent]; in the appDidFinishLaunching to set it for the whole application

Comment: That's what my issue is - implementing preferredStatusBarStyle in the UIViewControllers and/or using '- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent; 
}' in the AppDelegate doesn't work unless I set the View controller-based status bar appearance to NO and if I do this then my status bar is just hidden UNLESS I hide the status bar during application launch, which is driving me crazy. I also notice that no matter if I do the above the status bar is the wrong colour during application launch and when using MailComposer.

Comment: I've edited my answer, to support the initially hidden behavior

Comment: you cant call preferredStatusBarStyle inside the AppDelegate since it is not a UIViewController. Please actually read my answer since everything should be clear. The color for the application launch and the MailComposer are set by the OS and not your application so what ever you do the set the color inside your app doesn't affect those.

Comment: I apologize, I did not mean to set preferredStatusBarStyle inside the AppDelegate.  I have fixed the MailComposer issue with a quick: '[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:^{[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];}];' However, my mind is still boggled as to why Hiding the status bar during application launch messes everything up. Thanks for you help by the way.